# new nodes always becomes the first node in my single linkedlist

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've been learning the implementation of single linked list in c++.
Thing is that I understood the concept behind single linked list but I am not able to guess where I have done mistake in the code.
**Whenever I insert a new node, it takes the first position (i.e head) and the size of the list is always 1.**
I tried to solve it but **sometimes display function turns into infinite loop**.
I am getting no clue on this.
Its been pricking my mind for a week.

All I can guess is, I am not referencing the addresses properly in the code.
Am I messing up with the pointers? Help by making me understand the mistake I have done.Thank you.

SLLCLAS.CPP

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

class node{
    public:
        int data;
        node *next;
};

class sll{
    private:
        node *head;
    public:
        ssl(){
            head=NULL;
        }
        void display();
        void insert(int,int);
};

void sll::display(){
    if(head==NULL){
        cout<<"List is Empty";
    }else{
        cout<<"\n";
        for(node *t=head;t!=NULL;t=t->next){
        cout<<t->data<<"->";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

void sll::insert(int position,int data){
    node *temp=new node();
    temp->data=data;
    if(position<0){
        cout<<"\nPosition not valid";
    }else if(head==NULL || position==1){
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }else{
        node *p,*q;
        q=head;
        int count=1;
        while(count<position && q!=NULL){
        count++;
        cout<<"\nCount:"<<count;
        p=q;
        q=q->next;
    }
    p->next=temp;
    temp->next=q;
    delete(temp);
}

int main(){
    clrscr();
    sll list;
    int ch,val,pos;
    do{
        cout<<"\nSINGLY LINKED LIST\n1: Insert\n2: Delete\n3: Display\n Enter your choice:";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
                cout<<"\nEnter the position:";
                cin>>pos;
                cout<<"\nEnter the value:";
                cin>>val;
                list.insert(pos,val);
                list.display();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                list.display();
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"\nWrong choice";
        }
        cout<<"\nDo you want to continue(1/0):";
        cin>>ch;
    }while(ch!=0);
    getch();
}


EDIT:
```

I am running the code on Turbo C++ Version 3.0 on windows 8.1 64bit
   using dosbox.

Comment: indent your code. stop using IO into your data structure functions.

Comment: please provide a readable example without the debug code

Comment: `<iostream.h>`? The header should be `<iostream>`. Also, where did you learn that semicolons follow the #include directive?  As to your problem, did you draw the linked list on paper first?  You should do that before writing one line of code.  Once you have the idea of how the links work *on paper*, you transfer what you have on paper to a C++ program.  If the C++ doesn't work correctly, you need to know where your program deviates from the plan.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that one (semicolons) was me, I think (the online formatter I was using screwed things up, so I reverted)

Comment: 1. Giving position as number isn't friendly for lists, `ssl::insert` should take position as pointer or iterator.

2. Use constructor (`ssl::ssl()`) instead of `void ssl::initList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fixed version of the function `insert`:

```
void sll::insert(int position, int data) {
    node* temp = new node();
    temp->data = data;
    if (position <= 0) {
        cout << "\nPosition not valid";
    } else if (head == NULL || position == 1) {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;   // ---------------------- problem here
    } else {
        node* p, *q;
        q = head;
        int count = 1;
        while (count < position && q != NULL) {
            count++;
            cout << "\nCount:" << count;
            p = q;
            q = q->next;
        }
        p->next = temp;
        temp->next = q;
    }
    //delete (temp); //<---------------- problem here
}
```

- You create a node to insert in the list but at the end of the function deleted (with pointer referencing to this memory address), when accessing the memory deleted anything could happen.
- The other problem would give you compiler error you are assigning a `node` variable to a `node*` variable, with what compiler you are testing.
- The are other problems as `#include <iostream.h>`, iostream is a header from C++ that don't have extension (ex: `#include <vector>` or `#include <iostream>`).
- The main function it's not standart, changed to `int main()` if the parameters are not used or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` if they are. You would need to return and integer from `main` function.
- I don't have `clrscr();` function defined, probably platform dependent (i am testing with MinGW GCC 4.9.0 with C++11 in Windows).

Comment: inserting at head or position 1 is not the same if position 0 is a valid position... you'll have to decide on a) using 0-based indexing or b) changing the first if condition to (position <= 0)

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
delete(temp);
```

is highly suspicious in the `insert` function.

Basically `temp` reference the new node you take care to create and setup. But you delete it before exiting the function. After the first `insert`, you are manipulating freed memory.

The statement

```
head=*temp;
```

make no sense. `head` is a `node*`, and you are assigning a `node` value. If it ever compiles, head is also containing garbage value.

Comment: head=*temp was noob!!! sorry.But when i last compiled i used head=temp.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
   struct node
    {
     int info;
     node *next;
    };

 class DS
  {
    private:
    node *temp;
    node *temp1;
    node *head;
    int key;
    int x;
    public:
    DS()
    {
       head=temp=temp1=NULL;
     }

   void insert()
   {
       for (int i=0; i<1; i--)
     {
          cout<<"Enter 0 to stop and 1 to continue:";
          cin>>x;
          cout<<endl;
          if (x==1)
          {
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        head=new node;
        cout<<"Enter the value in head's Info";
        cin>>head->info;
        cout<<endl;
        head->next=NULL;

    }

    cout<<"Enter the number after which you want to add node:";
    cin>>key;
    cout<<endl;
    temp=head;

    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp->info==key)
        {
            temp1=new node;
            cout<<"Enter value in new node:";
            cin>>temp1->info;
            cout<<endl;
            temp1->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=temp1;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
        }
        else break;

   }
    }

void Del()
{
    temp=head;
    if(head==NULL)
        return;
    cout<<"Enter the number after which you want to delete the node:";
    cin>>key;
    cout<<endl;
    while( temp!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp->next->info==key)
        {
            temp1=temp->next;
            temp->next=temp->next->next;
            delete temp1;
            break;
        }

            temp=temp->next;
    }
}

   void searching()
   {
    temp=head;
    cout<<"Enter key to found node:";
    cin>>key;
    cout<<endl;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp->info==key)
        {
            cout<<"Node found"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void printing()
{
    temp=head;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<temp->info<<endl;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void emptiness()
{
    temp=head;
    if (temp->next==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Empty list";
            cout<<endl;
    }
    else if (temp!=NULL)
        cout<<"Not empty";
}
};

   int main()
 {
    DS obj;
    obj.insert();
    cout<<endl;
    obj.Del();
    cout<<endl;
    obj.searching();
    cout<<endl;
    obj.printing();
    cout<<endl;
    obj.emptiness();

   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanatory notes to supplement your code?